# Failing to start vmms - Not enough storage space

Tags: hyper-v, hyper-v-server-2016

I'm running Hyper-v on Win Server 2016 and a VM went unresponsive to I went to restart it via Hyper-V management console. It got stuck rebooting so I'm now trying to resolve that, but things are getting worse as I go along. All other VM's are still currently working so I'm trying to recover without rebooting the entire physical host.

I've managed to stop the vmms service, but when trying to restart, i'm getting an incorrect error of:

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> net start vmms
The Hyper-V Virtual Machine Management service is starting.
The Hyper-V Virtual Machine Management service could not be started.
A system error has occurred.
System error 14 has occurred.
Not enough storage is available to complete this operation.
```

There is plenty of storage space on the host.

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> Get-Volume

DriveLetter FileSystemLabel FileSystem DriveType HealthStatus OperationalStatus SizeRemaining    Size
----------- --------------- ---------- --------- ------------ ----------------- -------------    ----
C                           NTFS       Fixed     Healthy      OK                      7.99 TB 9.09 TB
            Recovery        NTFS       Fixed     Healthy      OK                    135.06 MB  450 MB
D           D               NTFS       Fixed     Healthy      OK                      8.33 TB  9.1 TB
```

Apart from the obvious host reboot, which I'm trying to avoid, any suggestions on how to recover this?

**Update :**
Looking at Server Manager > Hyper-V I'm seeing the following trying to start vmms:

```
SERVER5 14096   Error   Microsoft-Windows-Hyper-V-VMMS  Microsoft-Windows-Hyper-V-VMMS-Admin    20/12/2023 13:32:14
```

If I go to Hyper-V Manager it is not connected to any servers, if i try 'Connect to Server' and chose 'Local Server' I get `Hyper-V encountered an error trying to access an object on computer 'SERVER5' because the object was not found. Verify that the Virtual Machine Management service on the computer is running`.

If I try running `net start vmms` it still gives me the same storage error, but then in Event Logs is gives the memory error.

Comment: and how much rum is free? what is the busines related question in here?

Comment: @djdomi Thanks for taking the time to reply. The error quotes storage, not memory, but memory utilisation is 20% so that is not the issue either. "Business related question?" - what do you mean?

Comment: What research has been done? You mask want to read carefully [ask] due Questions on Server Fault must be about managing information technology systems in a business environment. Home and end-user computing questions may be asked on Super User. Inhere are missing, what has been already done to solve it, why is a reboot not an option?

Comment: @djdomi I asked on serverfault.com because this is a server (I explained that in my original post). I provided the information in my original post such as errors and what I have tried. I also explained in my original post that I would prefer to not reboot because there are other working VM's on the host.

Comment: check the event logs for more detailed information on the issue. Look for any specific error codes or messages related to the failure of the service

Comment: @Turdie Thaks for replying. Only thing in the Event Log is "The Hyper-V Virtual Machine Management service terminated with the following error: Ran out of memory." but this is just not true : `FreePhysicalMemory TotalVisibleMemory
------------------ ------------------
         322978724`

Comment: That message `Not enough storage is available` is not referring to disk or memory storage. It is a generic error that does not contain sufficient information for analysis, and could be a second or third level symptom, not related to the actual problem.

Comment: @GregAskew thanks for your reply. That's the only info I have. The message in my OP when trying to start vmms and then what appears in the Event Log which states that it is memory (not storage, conflicting with the other message) related. I'll update the OP as the situation has now changed.

Comment: did you check the filesystem for errors? Moreover, "serverfault" should be renamed to business fault where only business envoirmental question can be asked from business administrators ;-) Because running a server alone, does not make it on topic for serverfault

Comment: @djdomi Thanks for your valuable input on this post

Comment: I found this `To restart the VMMS service using the command prompt:
1.On the computer that has the stopped service, open a command prompt as local administrator and type the following:
net stop nvpswmi
If the service is not running, you will see the error "The Hyper-V Networking Management service is not started."
3.On the command prompt type the following command to start the nvpswmi service
net start nvspwmi
If the service start starts you will see the message "The Hyper-V Networking Management service was start successfully."`